Nothing prints when receiving text from a socket
I have created a client program and a server program. When the client sends the message, it doesn't have any errors and sends it. On the other end, the server receives it and says "message received printing on next line:" but nothing is outputted.
Here is the code.
Client:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[20] = "Hello from a client";
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    printf("Not Working\n");
    return -1;
  }
  struct sockaddr_in feetpics;
  feetpics.sin_family = AF_INET;
  feetpics.sin_port = htons(8080);
  feetpics.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)&feetpics;
  socklen_t sockbuf;
  sockbuf = sizeof(feetpics);
  if (connect(sockfd, addr, sockbuf) < 0 ) {
    printf("couldn't establish a connection with 127.0.0.1\n");
    return -1;
  } else {
    struct sockaddr_in jaycar;
    struct sockaddr *radioshack = (struct sockaddr *)&jaycar;
    socklen_t jaycarbuf = sizeof(jaycar);
    getpeername(sockfd, radioshack, &jaycarbuf);
    printf("connected to %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(jaycar.sin_addr), ntohs(jaycar.sin_port));
    size_t ben = strlen(buffer);
    int flags = MSG_CONFIRM;
    size_t result = send(sockfd, "Hello", 5, flags);
    if (result < 0) {
      printf("Message not sent\n");
      return -1;
    } else {
      printf("Hello message sent\n");
    }
  }
}

Server:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
// By RCS
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char buffer[100];
  int port = atoi(argv[1]);
  int incomingsocks;
  int backlog = 3;
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
    printf("Failed\n");
    return -1;
  }
  struct sockaddr_in socks;
  socks.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 address family
  socks.sin_port = htons(port); // port number
  socks.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // IPv4 address
  struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)&socks;
  if (bind(sockfd, addr, sizeof(socks)) < 0) {
    printf("FATAL: Socket could not be created\n");
    return -1;
  } else {
    printf("NOTICE: Socket binded successfully \n");
    if (listen(sockfd, backlog) < 0) {
      printf("FATAL: Cannot Listen\n");
      return -1;
    } else {
      printf("NOTICE: listening to port %d\n", ntohs(socks.sin_port));
    }
    socklen_t sockbuf;
    sockbuf= sizeof(socks);
    while (1) {
      incomingsocks = accept(sockfd, addr, &sockbuf);
      if (incomingsocks < 0) {
        printf("FATAL: Won't accept connections\n");
        return -1;
      } else {
        printf("NOTICE: Someone has connected\n");
      }
      int flags = MSG_WAITALL;
      size_t receiveres = recv(incomingsocks, buffer, strlen(buffer), flags);
      if (receiveres < 0) {
        printf("NOTICE: No data sent from connected person\n");
      }
      if (buffer == NULL) {
      printf("WARNING: A message has been received, but it wasn't written to the buffer");
      } else {
        printf("Message received printing on next line: \n");
        buffer[receiveres] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buffer);
      }
    }
  }
}

I have tried to find alternatives for send and recv. I have also tried flags, and different ways of outputting.

Minor: Rather than buffer[receiveres] = '\0'; printf("%s", buffer);, use fwrite(buffer, 1, receiveres, stdout);.  This avoids forming a string and correctly prints all characters even if a null character was read.

size_t result = send(sockfd, "Hello", 5, flags);
if (result < 0) { // can never be true since size_t is unsigned.

Use ssize_t as specificed as the return type for send and recv instead. You have the same issue on the receiving side.
Also, if(buffer == NULL) doesn't make sense. buffer is a char[100] and will never be NULL.
The problem making it impossible to receive messages is however that you tell recv that the buffer size is strlen(buffer). That strlen can return anything since buffer is uninitialized and I'm guessing it returns 0 for you. You should use sizeof buffer instead:
ssize_t receiveres = recv(incomingsocks, buffer, sizeof buffer, flags);
if (receiveres == -1) {
    perror("recv");
} else if (receiveres == 0) {
    puts("client shutdown");
} else {
    puts("Message received printing on next line:");
    printf("%.*s\n", (int) receiveres, buffer);
}

If you want to null terminate buffer like you do now, use sizeof buffer - 1 instead.

Thank you Ted Lyngmo, I'm new to socket programming and to C as a whole

@Rioboyva2554 You're welcome! Glad it helped!


In your server code:

size_t receiveres = recv(incomingsocks, buffer, strlen(buffer), flags);

well, this is calculating the buffer size as the size of the string stored in the buffer, which is Undefined Behaviour, because you haven't initialized the buffer at all.  You should write sizeof buffer instead of strlen() as you need to pass the total buffer size to recv.

The line

if (buffer == NULL)

is incorrect, as you have declared buffer as an array of char, buffer will ALLWAYS be different than NULL.

The line

buffer[receiveres] = '\0';

is subject to a buffer overrun if it happens that you receive exactly the sizeof buffer number of characters.  You will overwrite the character past the last cell of the buffer.  U.B. again.  You should pass sizeof buffer - 1 to recv to be allowed to do this.

A good idea is to use strerror(errno) when signalling an error, this way you give the user a kernel produced error message, which will tell you better why your system call failed.

In client code, you don't check the result of getpeername() so you cannot know what happened or if an error was made.


You server code, after some changes correcting the above indications is:
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h> /* to use strerror() */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEFAULT_BACKLOG     (3)
#define DEFAULT_PORT        (8080)

// By RCS
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    if (argc >= 2)
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int backlog = DEFAULT_BACKLOG;
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "FATAL: socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in socks = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET, // IPv4 address family
        .sin_port   = htons(port), // port number
        .sin_addr   = {
        .s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"), // IPv4 address
        },
    };

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&socks, sizeof socks) < 0) {
        printf("FATAL: Socket could not be bound: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("NOTICE: Socket bound successfully\n");
        if (listen(sockfd, backlog) < 0) {
          printf("FATAL: Listen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          return -1;
        }
        printf("NOTICE: listening to port %d\n", ntohs(socks.sin_port));

        socklen_t sockbuf;
        sockbuf = sizeof(socks);
        struct sockaddr_in client;

        while (1) {
            int incomingsocks = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sockbuf);
            if (incomingsocks < 0) {
                printf("FATAL: accept: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            } else {
                printf("connection from %s:%d\n",
                        inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),
                        ntohs(client.sin_port));
            }
            int flags = MSG_WAITALL;
            char buffer[100];
            size_t receiveres = recv(incomingsocks, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1, flags);
            if (receiveres < 0) {
                /* this is an error */
                printf("NOTICE: recv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                close(incomingsocks);
                continue;
            }
            buffer[receiveres] = '\0';
            printf("Message received: %s\n", buffer);
        } /* while */
    } /* else */
} /* main */

and client code is:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT (8080)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    if (argc > 1) {
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    char buffer[] = "Hello from a client";
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("FATAL: socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in feetpics = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port   = htons(port),
        .sin_addr   = {
            .s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"),
        },
    };
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&feetpics, sizeof feetpics) < 0 ) {
        printf("couldn't establish a connection with 127.0.0.1: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in jaycar;
    socklen_t jaycarsiz = sizeof jaycar;

    if (getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &jaycar, &jaycarsiz) < 0) {
        printf("getpeername: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    printf("connected to %s:%d\n",
            inet_ntoa(jaycar.sin_addr),
            ntohs(jaycar.sin_port));

    ssize_t result = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    if (result < 0) {
        printf("Message not sent: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\"%s\" message sent\n", buffer);
} /* main */

